# How to select all links in a page and store it in an array in capybara?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

```
When(/^I search for all links on homepage$/) do
  within(".wrapper") do
    all("a")[0].text
  end

  all_link = []
  all_link << all("a")[0].text
  all_link.each do |i|
    puts i
  end
end
```

This is the code i have written to get the text of the link. But here only one link text is available. I have to manually provide all 'a' values to call up the elements and store the text. Is there some other way in which I can use the url and call up all the links and the related text to that link and store it in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When(/^I search for all links on homepage$/) do
  within(".wrapper") do
    all_links = all("a").map(&:text) # get text for all links
    all_links.each do |i|
      puts i
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: OP stated there is a need to get _text_, so, yes, links themselves are not included.

Answer (score 1):

```
all_links = all("a").map { |ele| [ ele[:href], ele.text ] }
```

This would give you an array of pairs with the URLs and their associated text (I assume you mean the text inside the `<a>` element, not the web page you get by following on the link).

By the way, to output them for debugging purposes, a simpler way is

```
puts all_links.inspect
```